# How to make a user defined namespace in c#

Tags: c#, namespaces

I have the following two files in Visual Studio:

```
//file1.cs
using System;
namespace Pointns{
    public class Point{
        public float x;
        public float y;
        public Point(){
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
        }
    }
}

//file2.cs
using System;
using Pointns;
namespace test1{
    class test2{
        static void Main(){
            Point p1 = new Point();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
            Console.WriteLine(p1.x);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to compile it says it cannot locate `Pointns`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are these two files? In what kind of project?

Comment: It's a console project. I'm just trying to learn how to link code from two separate files.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything. Just build the project. Are there errors in both files? The one defining the namespace has to build before the namespace can be referenced. Also, please edit your question to show the exact error message.

Comment: Can you paste the exact error message?

Comment: 1 error: Error The type or namespace name 'Pointns' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Chris\Documents\test1\file2.cs 3 7 testProject1

Comment: Both files  belong to the same project?  Both files are "included" in that project?

Comment: Both files are in the exact same folder. `file2.cs` runs fine on its own if I remove any reference to `Pointns` and `Point`.

Comment: Okay, but is "file1.cs" "included" in your project.  Maybe you accidentally removed it from the project which would leave it in the same folder.  Just trying to brainstorm.

Comment: By compile I mean that I am clicking "Start" with the green arrow.

Comment: Maybe it's not "included", haven't come across that topic yet. Ill look into how that works.

Comment: If you don't have the "show all files" enabled and you can still see the file listed under your project in the solution explorer, then it's included.

Comment: That was the problem. I did "project->add existing item" and now its working. Thanks!

Comment: Great!  I worked it up as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take into consideration the following things:

- Are the two files in the same project?  If not, you will need to add a reference to the target project (the one that contains file1.cs).
- Are both files "included" in your project?  If you don't have the "show all files" option enabled and you cannot see the file listed under your project in the solution explorer, then you need to add the file to your project (even if it's in the same folder.  To do this, enable the "show all files" option (via the button at the top of the solution explorer) and then right-click on the file that appears in your project and select "include in project"; alternately, you can right-click on the project and choose "add > existing item".